# After re-installing Windows XP I've got a folder I don't have rights to any more. How can I regain control?

Tags: windows-xp, permissions

On my second hard drive there's this folder:

D:\73dca78350f1e7f756d03ee8

It contains two sub folders - "amd64" and "i386".

After re-installing Windows XP I can no longer access these folders. I just get "Access denied". These are the only two folders on the disk that I can't access.

How can I regain control of these two folders?

I'm logged in with Administrator rights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried taking ownership of the folders? These are normally remnants of a Windows Update or Windows Installer program.

There is a detailed guide on how to do this available [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308421).

Comment: That page talks about the "Security" tab on the properties dialog with an "Advanced" button. I've only got a "Sharing" tab with no "Advanced" button. Which is because I've got "Simple File Sharing" enabled. Disabling it gives me the "Security" tab

Answer (score 2):

You can give `CACLS` a go:

```
cacls "D:\73dca78350f1e7f756d03ee8" /E /T /C /G "Administrator":F
```

replace **Administrator** with the user you wish to delegate control to.