# Curious folder on the root of volume on windows server 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Random directories in c:\ that I cannot delete](https://superuser.com/questions/132176/random-directories-in-c-that-i-cannot-delete)

We have just set up a new windows 2008 R2 server with three separate raid arrays as drives C:, F: and I:. After installing all the windows updates and Trend Micro anti virus, we see at the root of our F: volume a folder named "c323e2a243c313f307e247fd" containing only an empty folder named "Sandbox". It has unique security applied

Where might it have come from? And what if we delete it?

Comment: How to delete is here...http://superuser.com/questions/321468/unable-to-delete-folder-in-windows-7

Comment: Not sure question belongs... [Servervault](http://servervault.com) may be better.

Comment: Also see [What's this folder?: c8c6ac6192a47b59df](http://superuser.com/questions/132911/whats-this-folder-c8c6ac6192a47b59df)