# How can I stop getting these folders containing a 0 byte amd64 folder?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

Every (other?) day I get a bunch of these crazy named folders appearing in the home drive C:. The names are basically like those this user talks about ([What's this folder?: c8c6ac6192a47b59df](https://superuser.com/questions/132911/whats-this-folder-c8c6ac6192a47b59df)) except I get ten or more of them appearing. All the other similarly asked questions regard issues with opening and deleting them, which is not what I am experiencing. I can open the folder, and all of them contain another folder labeled amd64 with nothing inside that folder. I can delete them, but more folders like it continue to be created. What can I do to figure out and stop the root cause of this issue?

I'm running 64-bit Windows 7.

Comment: Like what the answer you pointed said, the most likely culprit is Windows Update (although I'm not in Windows 7 so I can't confirm).

Comment: Do you have the "Don't show Hidden files, folders, or drives" radio button selected in your Folder Options?

Comment: @yassarikhan786 I do not have that selected.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard I saw that too, didn't think Windows update happened at the frequency that I was seeing these folders pop up (not to mention MANY of them, instead of just one folder like everyone else). I'll investigate that route though, just in case.

Comment: @echoecho Select it and see what happens.

Comment: @yassarikhan786 did it, not sure what I am expecting? The folders don't go away (don't think they are hidden folders, usually icons for hidden folders are a bit translucent?)

Comment: @echoecho assume that for each individual update Windows Update caches, you need a folder. They "should" be out of sight, but it isn't rare for them to appear at the root directory, because it's there where they are made (so, Windows Update just does not tidy up after himself).

Comment: @echoecho You are right. Hidden folders do indeed be translucent.