# Mysterious folder on hard disk

Tags: windows

I found a mysterious folder named `e849ad3686d570a415` in the root of a hard disk. It contains a subfolder `i386` which is inaccessible.

Do I have malware on my PC? How can I delete this folder?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's an installation folder. I have one with an "amd64" and "i386" folder. The contents of the "i386" folder look like the installation files for a printer driver.

To take control of a folder see the answers to [my question](https://superuser.com/questions/111697/after-re-installing-windows-xp-ive-got-a-folder-i-dont-have-rights-to-any-more) on the subject. Don't forget to turn "Simple File Sharing" off.

Answer (score 1):

Malware is an outside possibility, but would normally do a better job of masquerading as something sensible and necessary.  It is most likely debris left over from the install of some 32-bit software.  Take a backup of it; remove it.  If nothing witters over the next couple of weeks, you were safe.  The name suggests that is not intended to be a permanent directory.

Answer (score 1):

- Thats **NOT Malware**
- This is a conventional folder name, that Microsoft uses to place files in. The numbers (e849ad3686d570a415) represent **Hexadecimal coding** in set of pairs (e8 49 ad 36 86 d5 70 a4 15) so that it will not be recognized by software.
- **TO DELETE**

  > **1)** Go to "tools" menu at the top
  >
  > **2)** Choose "folder options"
  >
  > **3)** Under View Tab deactivate the
  >   option "use simple file sharing"
  >
  > **4)** Now Select the Folder You wan to
  >   delete
  >
  > **5)** Right click on it and select
  >   "Sharing and security"
  >
  > **6)** Under Security Tab
  >
  > **7)** Add User to List
  >
  > **8)** Then Below in Permissions
  >
  > **9)** Select "Full Control"
  >
  > **10)** Apply and OK

Resource from  [here](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-a-mac-address.htm)

Comment: Why do you say "in set of pairs"? That would be typical of text coding, but this doesn't look like it - not ASCII anyway.

Comment: Oh I am sorry but all the contents in my answer have been taken from a valid resource and I think I forgot to provide the Resource. I don't remember the website now. I will post it if I find it

Comment: ok Updated my answer with the Resource link