# Prevent "mysterious" folders in drive root from appearing without disabling Windows Update

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

In [this question](https://superuser.com/q/187401/82470) it is asked and answered *why* mysterious folders appear at the root of my D-drive periodically, named `e849ad3686d570a415`, `57431c392d6db70ad5bfcd1a6676a241`, etc, containing folders like `i386` and `amd64`: they're leftovers from Windows updates. It is also explained there that *it is safe to delete those folders*.

In fact, there are more similar/related questions:

- [Mysterious folder on hard disk](https://superuser.com/q/187401/82470)
- [What are these folders created on my Western Digital 2TB Mirror?](https://superuser.com/q/382305/82470)
- [Windows Updates Folders (With Strange Names) in C drive](https://superuser.com/q/130125/82470)

None of these questions or their answers explain how to prevent it from happening, apart from the obvious conclusion to just disable the root cause (Windows update) entirely.

So my specific question then is: **How can I stop this from happening**, *without* resorting to rigorous solutions such as disabling Windows Update, moving over to Linux, etc., and without resorting to creating an after-the-fact solution (e.g. a scheduled task to delete these folders)? Is that possible?

What I've tried so far is looking for a way to find out what specific process generates these folders so I can narrow my search for a solution. I've found [this question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/q/20668) about a general way to find out such things, but it isn't very helpful. I've tried checking who the owner of those folders is, but `MY-PC\Administrators` doesn't tell me much either. I've tried `dir e849ad3686d570a415 | format-list *` in Powershell, but it tells me nothing of interest. I've [Googled](https://www.google.nl/search?q=cause%20of%20new%20folders%20in%20root%20of%20disk%20i386%20amd64) around but that mainly leads to aforementioned question.

**Bottom line:**
How can I stop these folders from appearing? Removing them by hand is getting pretty old and writing a script or task to do this periodically "feels dirty".

Comment: [Mysterious folder on hard disk](http://superuser.com/questions/187401/mysterious-folder-on-hard-disk?rq=1), [What are these folders created on my Western Digital 2TB Mirror?](http://superuser.com/questions/382305/what-are-these-folders-created-on-my-western-digital-2tb-mirror)

Comment: Thx for the tips (hadn't seen those yet), but they are *not* duplicates as the accepted answers indicate the actual question was either "are these folders harmful?", "wat are those folders?" or "can I delete those folders?". My question is different: I want to know how I can find out what is *causing* these folders to appear and how I can eliminate the cause.

Comment: _As several of the other answers point out: It's Windows Update (or possible another updater) that hasn't cleaned up after itself_.  If you really want to audit the folder for what's adding these, turn on and setup Folder/File Auditing and wait until another appears, then use the audit logs to track it down.

Comment: Thx, good to know! I couldn't quite distill that from those other answers. Second part of my question remains: *how do I stop it from happening?*

Comment: Turn off Windows Updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some redistributable installers and/or updates from Microsoft extract their files to a subdirectory (or even root directory!) of the drive with the most free space or your system drive. You cannot do anything to stop this, because it’s the installers’ fault.
The only “workaround” would be not to install or update *anything*.

Comment: Thanks DanielB for taking the time to answer. The bounty was automatically removed by the system when our mod @random found [a question that *is* a duplicate](http://superuser.com/questions/140/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-installs-updates-to-litter-my-hard-drive-with-cryptic). Though it saddens me to learn all we can do is put up with this, it does mean your answer is correct. I can't open a bounty anymore (to "reward existing answer" here) as my question's closed, so you'll have to make do with +1, an accept, and my gratitude.

Comment: No worries. :-)

Answer (score -3):

My [answer](https://superuser.com/a/130137/8672) to the post [Windows Updates Folders (With Strange Names) in C drive](https://superuser.com/questions/130125/windows-updates-folders-with-strange-names-in-c-drive)
hasn't changed :

These are left-overs from Windows Update.

(This post is actually a duplicate.)

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I must respectfully disagree. This is *not a duplicate*. The other question asks and gets answers to what the folders *are*, and if it's *safe to remove them*. I want to know **how to prevent these folders from appearing**. The other question and answer do *not* address that.

Comment: Although you down-voted me, this question is also answered here: Disable Windows Update and these folders will not appear again. However, Metro updates are unblockable. With all due respect, for disabling Windows Update - this cure is worse than the problem of having some funny-named folders that are easily deleted.

Comment: The downvote is for the *answer*, as it's not useful to me and IMHO is not an actual answer to the question posed (my question is not a duplicate). It's certainly not personal, like I said: I appreciate your help! - The curse you talk about (disabling updates) is of course not an option (I -perhaps mistakenly- didn't mention it in the question, figuring that this would be a given). If your comment holds true, then @DanielB's answer would sadly be an actual answer to my question: "you cannot do anything to stop this".

Comment: If my comment holds true, then sadly your post _is_ duplicate.

Comment: Where in that supposed duplicate question is asked "how to prevent it from happening"? Nowhere. Where in the supposed duplicate is there an answer that explains "you cannot do anything to stop this"? Nowhere. ... But perhaps we should just agree to disagree ;-)