# Empty system folders crated on drive root daily

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, vmware-player

I have a secondary drive linked to a VMWare Player Windows 8.1 machine from a Windows 7 host. Every day a number of randomly named folders are created on the disk root, all empty. To delete them you need admin rights, and I have to keep cleaning them every other day to not pollute the disk with tens of them.

Screenshot:

[image]

Any guesses on whether the host, the guest or VMWare is the one creating those folders?

Comment: Let me guess.  This external/secondary drive is larger then your system drive?  The folders names are not "random" they are Windows Update folders.

Comment: Yes and that was my guess. How can I purge them automatically?

Comment: If you purge them you remove your ability to uninstall those updates

Comment: Why are they stored on the root folder? Can I at least hide them? The clutter is the annoying part because that's mainly my storage drive without all the windows/program files noise.

Comment: Windows Update attempts to find the largest storage drive.  It does this so it won't run out of the space.  [There are numerous questions on these folders](http://superuser.com/questions/719467/prevent-mysterious-folders-in-drive-root-from-appearing-without-disabling-wind?rq=1).

Comment: At some point this just stopped happening.