# Copy a harddrive from a failed desktop machine using a second working one

Tags: backup, desktop-computer

Heres the scenario:

I have `PC-A`, an old PC that runs Windows XP but now refuses to boot due to a failed motherboard (or maybe PSU).  This PC has a single 80gb IDE drive.

I also have `PC-B`, running Windows Vista, this is working fine.

I want to copy all the data off `PC-As` HDD onto `PC-B`.  To do this I have taken the HDD out of `PC-A` and connected it as a slave to `PC-B`.  `PC-B` now boots and sees the additional drive.

However, when I attempt to access/copy user folders (i.e. Documents and Settings/[username]/*) I am told that I cannot access the folders due to user permissions.  I am doing this under an adminstrator account on `PC-B`.

So the question is, how can I "backup" the data? Preferably without making any changes to the drive contents.  The reason for this is that it is possible that `PC-A` is failing due to a bad PSU, so I intend to replace it before writing off the machine.  However I would feel much happier if I had a backup of the data on the HDD.

Comment: See the answers to my similar question on how to regain ownership of folders - http://superuser.com/q/111697/289

Comment: Problem is right now I don't want to change the permissions on the folder(s)/file(s) as it may be possible to resurect PC-A with a new PSU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to make any changes to the data on the disk at all, I recommend using a disk cloning utility (like [CloneZilla](http://www.clonezilla.org/) or [Ghost4Linux](http://sourceforge.net/projects/g4l/), which is available on the [Hiren's bootCD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/)) to create a full disk image.

Basically this reads the entire disk and writes the entire contents to an image file on another disk. This means you can restore the data to a state exactly like the day you created the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting with a Linux Live CD and mounting both drivers then copy what you want between them.

Ubuntu Live should auto-mount but not sure... personally I use "Trinity Rescue Kit".